# What is the best (most efficient, reliable, secure and fastest) method to store sessions in Django

Tags: python, django, session, memcached, session-cookies

I am working on a Django project where authentication happens externally through an API. So internally, I just have to remember whether a user is logged in or not (+ the account information) in session variables. The Django documentation gives a few options for storing session data:

1. Using database-backed sessions
2. Using cached sessions
3. Using write-through cache (cache and database)
4. Using file-based sessions
5. Using cookie-based sessions

I am not sure which one to use, what is your favorite and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

My Opinions:

I would recommend the write-through cache. It combines the database-backed sessions and cached sessions. The database-backed sessions is slower and the cached sessions is lack of persistence. The write-through cache combines them to make session persistent and faster.

Cookie-based sessions are fast while the data is small and insecure. But account information is not a good usage of it.

File-based session is not a good idea because it cannot scale, and it required disk I/O.

Comment: cookie-based session is more stateless, which means more scalable. +1

Comment: There is a term called JWT nowadays, not secure, no need to scale. But I am still looking for Redis for storing session. Only because that is fast. Not considering persistence, but secure.